# How does Axis2 handle requests? Is a new thread created for each request?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jboss, apache-axis

I have an axis2 web service written in Java deployed on Jboss.I want to maintain a global static variable whose life should be for an entire request-response. Basically each request should have it's own copy of the variable. So I wanted to know how to do this and if Axis2 already creates a separate thread with its own copy of variables for each request. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The threads will be the http threads from JBoss, Axis will as far as I know always use the container threads. For your needs you should look into ThreadLocal, just make sure you clean up the ThreadLocal variables before each request.

See for example this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/painless-introduction-javas-threadlocal-storage